# Pyspark: getting features for clustering from list

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, databricks

I don't have much experience on spark and I'm having some issues parsing data in order to apply clustering in Pyspark. Basically I have some users with some items associated.

Dataframe (df) is composed of rows (user, item). An user may be associated with more items (and also an item may be associated with many users). So there may be multiple rows with same user and different items.
Example:

```
user | item
1    |  45
2    |  58
3    |  2
1    |  97
1    |  2
2    |  3
...
```

I would like to cluster the users using the associated items information.

My approach was the following:

- I grouped on users transforming items in arrays. So my example df became like:

```
user | items
1    |  [2, 45, 97]
2    |  [3, 58]
3    |  [2]
...
```

- I transformed each item into a new list with n elements as the max item number and with values 0 or 1 depending on the item index. So after this my df became

```
user | items
1    |  [0,0,1,0,0,0,0, ...]
2    |  [0,0,0,1,0,0,0, ...]
3    |  [0,0,1,0,0,0,0, ...]
...
```

- I would use this to get lists for kmeans operating like this

```
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans, KMeansModel
def getRow(r):
    res = r['items']
    return res
kmtrain = df.rdd.map(lambda r: getRow(r))
model = KMeans.train(kmtrain, n_clusters, maxIterations=10, initializationMode="k-means||")
```

Problem is that this approach takes ages. It's clear that I'm doing something wrong here. Can help me understand where I'm doing mistakes?

Comment: If my assumption is correct, then item is a categorical variable, right? In that case, what's your definition of *nearness* between two items?

Comment: Yes, it's basically an ID that can only be treated as categorical. I was thinking of something like number of matches, so for example users associated with 'a cospicous number' of same items would end up in the same cluster, while users associated with different items would probably not.